# With regex, move words after dash to the beginning of each line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to move the word after the dash to the beginning of each line with a regex.

For example:

```
::absence – absense, absance
::acceptable – acceptible
::accidentally/accidently – accidentaly
```

Should be changed to:

```
absense, absance::absence – 
acceptible::acceptable – 
accidentaly::accidentally/accidently –
```

Comment: I don't really understand the behavior you want from this regex.  It looks like you are moving words around not adding them.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Regex isn't able to do this by itself. Tag your question with a language or program you are going to use for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find this regex:

```
(?m)^(::.+\ –\ )(.+)$
```

Replace it with this:

```
\2\1
```

In other regex tools, the replacement syntax may be `$2$1` instead.

[**Demo in regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/rN0i8n/2)

Explanation of the search regex:

```
(?m)     # enable the `m` flag for multiline mode (make ^ and $ match at line boundaries)
^        # at the start of the line
(        # capture the part before the dash
  ::       # the string '::'
  .+       # any characters right before…
  \ –\     # the string ' – '
)        # end the first capture
(.+)$    # capture the rest of the line
```

With Notepad++, you need to enable multiline mode with `(?m)` at the beginning because the interface has no other way to enable just that mode. Checking the “. matches newline” checkbox would also turn on `m`, but “. matches newline” should be unchecked or it will mess up the two `.+` in the regex.

Comment: `^(::[^-\n]+ – )(.+$)` if doing so multiline. +1 though

Comment: @ctwheels Thank you for your answer, but this code can do it per line, but I cannot get result In several lines with this regex, for example 20 lines

Comment: @RedScience did you enable multiline mode? You haven't presented us a language, but it's usually an `m` flag or an option that is passed into the regex method you're calling.

Comment: @ctwheels I am using this code In the Notepadd++ , How can I enable multiline mode?

Comment: @RedScience According to [the official wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Search_modifiers), by default, multiline mode follows the state of the “. matches newline” setting. In [Notepad++’s Replace dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R9u1.png), that checkbox is near the bottom left.

Comment: @RedScience However, turning on “. matches newline” would mess up the `(.+)$` in the regex. So you will have to use the “(?:flags-not-flags:...)” syntax described in [those docs](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Search_modifiers) to turn just the `m` modifier on. I think it’s referring to [this modifier syntax](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). You can apply `m` with it by surrounding the whole regex with `(?m ` `)`.

Comment: @rory-okane I do that but when I want to see the result, this regex code shows me result like this picture: https://i.imgur.com/fipKNk4.jpg

Comment: @RedScience As I realized in my [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134805/regex-add-a-word-after-dash-at-the-beginning-of-each-line#comment85284038_49134955), you have to disable “. matches newline” and write `(?m ^(::[^-]+ – )(.+)$)` instead.

Comment: @RedScience Actually, according to [How to use RegEx search modifiers in notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/1229093/how-to-use-regex-search-modifiers-in-notepad), Notepad++’s syntax is just `(?m)` added in front. So the regex will be `(?m)^(::[^-]+ – )(.+)$`.

Comment: I check this code again, but unfortunately problem not resolved, could you please check this regex code         (?m)^(::[^-]+ – )(.+)$ OR (?m ^(::[^-]+ – )(.+)$) both of them have the same result

Comment: (?m)^(::[^-]+ – )(.+)$ this code is near to our final result, but In this code lower words comes to the higher line, this code is the nearest code to our final result

Comment: @RedScience You were right, there was a bug in the regex. The `[^-]` was matching newlines as well. You could fix this by changing it to `[^-\n]`, but I changed it to `.` since that works just as well.